# What does the following assignment mean in the coffeescript snippet?

Tags: coffeescript

I saw a class A, after its class definition

```
class A
   constructor: (@x=0, @y=0) ->

@A = A
```

what does @A = A here?

Answer (score 2):

It helps to look at the generated output.

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.3
(function() {
  var A;

  A = (function() {
    function A(x, y) {
      this.x = x != null ? x : 0;
      this.y = y != null ? y : 0;
    }

    return A;

  })();

  this.A = A;

}).call(this);
```

So `@A` translates to `this.A`. When `this` is used at the top level, it refers to `window`. So `@A = A` exports the A class onto the window object.

This is normally done to export a library. For example, `window.$ = jQuery` or `window._ = lodash`.